# Sharepoint won't search Sub-Site

Tags: search, sharepoint-2007

We have a Sharepoint Intranet which has many sub-sites. Search boxes in sub-sites can search through the intranet but I want them to search only in their own sub-site. I tried to change search page url in search box web part properties but it didn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the search source and scopes, since by default your search boxes are using out of the box settings, which are pretty much set to "search everything".

Have a look at [this](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/SPCON010/SharePoint+Search+Configuration) to help you.

Comment: Blast! Beaten to the punch. http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/define-scopes-for-searches-HA010241119.aspx also has a pretty good overview.